# python : Noob IndexError

Tags: python, error-handling

I am currently trying to create a code that can scan a string, put the position of each letter found in a list associated to the letter (ex : if you find a S as the 35, 48 and 120 letter of the string, it will put 35, 48, and 120 in a list for the letter S). It will then put this list in a dictionary as a value with S for key.

My problem is simple, I have an IndexError: list assignment index out of range when I try to put the value in the list, but I cant find out why.

```
string = "Squalalanoussommespartisetjetedteste"
taille = len(string)
dico = dict()
dico = {}
i = 0
for i in range(taille):
    if string[i] == "A" or string[i] == "a" :
        va = 0
        valA = []
        valA[va] = i
        va = va + 1
        print(valA)
```

I apologize for my poor English, and thank by advance for the help.

Comment: you are trying to access item 0 in empty list => IndexError.
Use valA.append(i) which will append another item to your list (at the end) and you don't need to keep index va in your code.

Comment: Well, it just make the list take one element and then erase the former one. Maybe i did Something wrong ?

Comment: oh my goodness, you just blew my mind with the title of this question. It would be so awesome if certain errors (not necessarily simple ones) were named NoobIndexError and the like. If I ever write a programming language expect to be met with warnings about NoobErrors. Seriously what could be more hilarious than a rude interpreter/compiler. Also solutions would be bound to be easy to find on the net :D Thanks Raëgan, you made my day. PS. @AbishekKushnoor has the answer for you, except put `valA =[]` outside the for-loop :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify an index while pushing an item to a list in python. Try this:

```
for i in range(taille):
    if string[i] == "A" or string[i] == "a" :
        valA = []
        valA.append(i)
        print(valA)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it tells me that list object does not have push attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error in these lines

```
va = 0
valA = []
valA[va] = i
```

`valA` is blank list here, with zero elements, so when you try to assign a value to its `0` index, it raises `IndexError`.

Also to get indexes for each character you can directly loop over string, like

```
s = "Squalalanoussommespartisetjetedteste"
d = dict()
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    d.setdefault(c.lower(), []).append(i)
print d
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some errors in the code.

The index error is because you tried to call 0th position of an empty list.

```
valA = []
```

The list is empty. Then you tried to replace value at the 0th position when there is no 0th position

```
valA[va] = i
```

I made some changes to the code. In the ninth line you initialize an empty list. You should do that before for loop. Otherwise for loop initiate it everytime and you lose the value in the previous loop.

here is the modified code.

```
string = "Squalalanoussommespartisetjetedteste"
taille = len(string)
dico = dict()
dico = {}
i = 0
valA = []
for i in range(taille):
    if string[i] == "A" or string[i] == "a":

        valA.append(i)
        print(valA)
```

The output i got is

```
[3, 5, 7, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you may use straightforward approach, Python has some usefull modules that may help. For example

```
import collections
s = "Squalalanoussommespartisetjetedteste"
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i,char in enumerate(s):
    result[char].append(i)
```

`result` would contain a dictionary with string characters as keys and lists if char's indexes as items.

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining variables below everytime. So move them to out of loop.

```
va = 0
valA = []
```

Also use insert method for list. (You can use insert for when you need to use define index in list. otherwise append is enough)

so final code :

```
string = "Squalalanoussommespartisetjetedteste"
taille = len(string)
dico = dict()
dico = {}
i = 0

va = 0
valA = []
for i in range(taille):
    if string[i] == "A" or string[i] == "a" :
        valA.insert(va, i)
        va = va + 1
        print(valA)
```

Answer (score 0):

index error, because array valA is empty array, that means there are no indexes...
use function append and declare array valA outside the loop...

```
string = "Squalalanoussommespartisetjetedteste"
taille = len(string)
dico = dict()
dico = {}
i = 0
valA = []
for i in range(taille):
    if string[i] == "A" or string[i] == "a" :
        valA.append(i)
        print(valA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an index error because your list is empty, which means you can't assign to index 0. When the list is empty you need to add the required value using method called append. #sorry for my english..!

```
string = "Squalalanoussommespartisetjetedteste"
taille = len(string)
dico = dict()
dico = {}
i = 0
for i in range(taille):
    if string[i] == "A" or string[i] == "a" :
        va = 0
        valA = []
        #valA[va] = i #error because list is empty
        valA.append(i)
        va = va + 1
        print(valA)
```